# JSON Path and StepFunction: Filter array based on value of various types

Tags: jsonpath, aws-step-functions, aws-stepfunctions-local

I have the following input:

```json
{
  "Context": {
    "fragments": [
      [
        {
          "variableId": "foo",
          "value": "121-121-121"
        },
        {
          "variableId": "bar",
          "value": "NOT_PROVIDED"
        },
        {
          "variableId": "baz",
          "value": "NOT_PROVIDED"
        },
        {
          "variableId": "qux",
          "value": 39
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "variableId": "quux",
          "value": {}
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "variableId": "corge",
          "value": 3000
        },
        {
          "variableId": "grault",
          "value": []
        },
        {
          "variableId": "garply",
          "value": "0"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice how `"value"` can be a string, an integer, an array

I would like to filter the input to keep only the values that are not equal to `"NOT_PROVIDED"` in a Pass state.

I tried the following expression on https://jsonpath.com/ which works:

```
$.Context.fragments[*][?(@.value != "NOT_PROVIDED")]
```

But fails with the following error on StepFunction with the following in a Parameter:

```json
{
  "payload.$": "$.Context.fragments[*][?(@.value != \"NOT_PROVIDED\")]"
}
```

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'Merge fragments in a single payload' (entered at the event id #46). Invalid comparison between different data types: $.Context.fragments[*][?(@.value != "NOT_PROVIDED")]
```

Can you please help me find a Json path expression that works in StepFunction, so that the output is:

```json
{
  "payload": 
      [
        {
          "variableId": "foo",
          "value": "121-121-121"
        },
        {
          "variableId": "qux",
          "value": 39
        },
        {
          "variableId": "quux",
          "value": {}
        },
        {
          "variableId": "corge",
          "value": 3000
        },
        {
          "variableId": "grault",
          "value": []
        },
        {
          "variableId": "garply",
          "value": "0"
        }
      ]
}
```

I tried the following expression on https://jsonpath.com/ which works:

```
$.Context.fragments[*][?(@.value != "NOT_PROVIDED")]
```

But fails with the following error on StepFunction with the following in a Parameter:

```json
{
  "payload.$": "$.Context.fragments[*][?(@.value != \"NOT_PROVIDED\")]"
}
```